# How can scatter the code to the core multi-core processor

Tags: multicore

Interested in:
1) Is it possible to do this in a unix like OS?
2) If it is possible to dig?

I would be happy all the answers.

Comment: Please be more specific: are you asking how to write code that runs on multiple cores in parallel? (this is indeed possible) What language are you using? (the answers will depend on that *tiny detail*) What do you mean, "is it possible to dig"? (That doesn't make any sense)

Comment: you need to be much clearer about your question and what you would like to know to get any useful answers.  Right now all I can suggest is that, yes it is possible.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either create multiple processes (e.g., fork) or multiple threads (e.g., pthread_create).